# chef - replace a running executable on windows

Tags: windows, chef-infra, windows-update

There is an executable - nssm - that is running in the background with multiple instances, and no really good way to stop it, and restart them all.

I would like to upgrade said binary, but it fails with a sharing violation.
Is there a cheffy way to trigger a reboot and copy the file into its location before/after the reboot takes place? (Like windows updates).

Thanks,

Comment: `nssm` is a service manager, so stopping the services using it should do well enough, where is you problem doing that ?

Comment: The windows EventLog holds an open lock on the binary, even if I stop all services, I am still unable to replace the binary

Comment: ... Event log service is a receiver, how could it hold a handler on an executable, do you have some anti-virus with acces inspection ?

Comment: Tbh, never really verified that it's the one holding the lock, something is, and I read somewhere that it would be responsible for it (although I did find that weird myself). And anyways listing all the services that are managed by nssm is currently not possible (planned feature), stopping each one and then restarting it seems like a more like a fragile workaround than a solution to this M$ limitation.

Comment: Well, I slightly disagree on the fragile statement. Replacing it without full picture of what is launched by it may break a service one day. I'll see what I can find, but replace at bootstrap sounds more risky to me. Have a look at process Explorer to find what is locking the file,  it's always better to know why something happen.